# C# calls Rscript but there is no output

Tags: c#, r

I need to call Rscript with C#.

I have a predict model in R. There is no problem when I run this R code in Rstudio.

But when I call this Rscript with C#, if the `readRDS()` function is in my R code there will not be any output.

Here is my C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rpath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\bin\Rscript.exe";
        var scriptpath = @"C:\test\cs_test2.R";
        var output = RunRScript(rpath, scriptpath);

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string RunRScript(string rpath, string scriptpath)
    {
        try
        {
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = rpath,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(scriptpath),
                Arguments = scriptpath,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            using (var proc = new Process { StartInfo = info })
            {
                proc.Start();
                return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {         Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here is my R code:

```r
get_pred <- function(){
EX<-read.csv("hospital1.csv")
PRE1<-readRDS("c:/Users/jun/Documents/test/FinalModel20200312.rds")
pred<-predict(PRE1,EX,type="prob")
return(pred)
}
get_pred()
```

if I just write a simple code like below , and it's good

```r
get_pred <- function(){
EX<-read.csv("hospital1.csv")
return(EX)
}
get_pred()
```

Comment: @JoshuaMire R can call `library(pkgname)` if they are in `.libPaths()`. To install packages in RStudio has nothing to do with this. Run at an operating system's prompt `Rscript -e '.libPaths()'` or in RStudio `.libPaths()` and the return values are most likely the same. If they are, RScript will find and call the installed packages.

Comment: @JoshuaMire The OP must post the R script, obviously.

Comment: Is there any output in proc.StandardError?

Comment: @JoshuaMire I post my r code ,

Comment: @Oleg no output

Comment: @jun Hsiao  what R package are you using for the `predict()` function?